# Intentional memory leak android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java2

Sometimes I have a function in a ViewModel something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
fun storeImportantUserAction(someData: SomeData) {
    storage.store(someData)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe()
}
```

I intentionally do not store the disposable and dispose of it when the user leaves the screen, because I definitely want this data to be stored and not have it possible for the user to interrupt that by pressing the back button.

I assume this will leak the Fragment until the store stream completes, and then the next garbage collection will successfully collect the Fragment. Is that correct? Would you recommend this approach?

Comment: No, a better approach is to have the data stored and retrieved an object that outlives the underlying `Fragment` and subscribe to changes on that object.

Comment: Then how do I manage the lifecycle of that underlying object?

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't need to manage the lifecycle of that underlying object since it lives longer than your fragment. This is how certain libraries work ie. expose the public API via a single instance object that you either inject into your activities, fragments etc. or call something like `LibraryObject.getInstance()` to retrieve their managed instance.

Comment: Fair enough, I would probably let the Storage object live for the life of the app as a singleton is what I mean. I see that as a more robust design, however in the actual case above, practically, I think it's fine, since the storage operation is short and will basically always finish before the Viewmodel is collected.